# Insert Results From Dynamic SQL Into 2 Table Variables

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute some dynamic SQL that will return 2 result sets and store the result sets in a table variable.

Let's say I have 2 tables (crappy schema but illustrates my issue)

Table1:

```
 ItemID int
 ItemName nvarchar(50)
```

Table2:

```
ItemId int
Quantity int
```

I generate some dynamic sql that looks like this:

```
DECALRE @sql varchar(max);
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * from Table2';
```

Then I create my table variables:

```
DECALRE @tbl1 TABLE (ItemId int, ItemName nvarchar(50))
DECALRE @tbl2 TABLE (ItemId int, Quantity int)
```

Then I want to execute that dynamic SQL and insert the results into the table variables I just declared. If there was just one result set in the dynamic sql I could simply just run this:

```
INSERT into @tbl1execute ('SELECT * FROM Table1;')
```

However, this obviously fails as soon as I use the @sql parameter that will return multiple result sets. Is this even possible?

Comment: No, you can't insert into two tables from one dynamic statement. Side note, you don't need dynamic sql here, at least from this watered down example. Also you are inserting into `@tbl1execute` which you haven't declared in your example. May I ask what the end goal is here? Perhaps there is a better, easier way... :)

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve by doing this? maybe there is a better way of doing what you are trying to do....

Comment: Yeah, this example here is crap but I was trying to illustrate the issue. The real example is we have a function that wraps a query with ROW OVER and gets the paging information such as total pages and whatnot and is meant to be used with Execute however i need to do some paging on another table that may or may not have records for the current page. My hope was to just throw the results in a variable and join but it looks like that isn't possible. Time to manually write that dang row over query and not rely on the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use temporary tables (not table variables):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(...)
CREATE TABLE #Table2(...)
DECLARE @MyDynamicSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    INSERT INTO #Table1(...)
    SELECT ...
    INSERT INTO #Table2(...)
    SELECT ...'
EXEC(@MyDynamicSql)
```

A couple of things to watch out for when writing this kind of spaghetti code however:

1. Re-running the same code (outside of a stored procedure) will necessitate dropping (or at least truncating) the temp tables
2. Addendum to the above: SQL parser will throw errors at you if you change the structure of the temp tables even if you have a `DROP` statement (read: you have to drop the tables before running the batch to change their structures)
3. If your process is a subroutine of one which already declared temp tables by the same name... Make sure to avoid that, I spent hours trying to figure this one out thinking I was going crazy.
4. Temp tables declared *inside* dynamic SQL need to be connection- or globally-scoped (2 and 3 `#`'s, respectively) to persist for the parent to access ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql))

Comment: Hey @Elaskanator, Thanks for the suggestion, however, this won't work for my situation, if you take a look at the comments on the original post you will see why. I do appreciate you taking the time though.